# When do overriden css rules take precedence?

Tags: html, css, firefox, sass

I'm trying to understand why an overridden CSS rule would still take priority over a rules that should be more CSS specific.  It doesn't have any `!important` property. (See screenshot below as well as the code snippet.)

```
header a {
    color: #fff;
}

a, a:active, a:focus, a:hover, a:visited {
    color: #001e62;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In the Firefox developer tools, I see that all `a` elements have a specific color(#001e62 in this screenshot).  After that, I specify that all `header a` links should be a different color(white in this example).  The Firefox developer tools reports that the `a` rule is overridden by the `header a` rule.  In the actual render of the page however, the link colors remain the color specified by the more general `a` rule.

For those wondering, the `span` inside the `a` tag in this screenshot does not have any color styling associated with it.
[image: Firefox Developer Tools CSS overridden weirdness]

If it matters, I'm using Firefox 55.0.3 on Windows 7.
Any insight as to why this happens would be helpful.  The behavior is only seen in Firefox so far. Chrome and IE do not do this.

After some initial Googling, I thought it could be because of quirks mode applying some weird inheritance rules, however I just have a standard HTML5 `DOCTYPE` tag, so I don't believe that should be an issue... It should be in full standards mode.

Comment: Please copy the relevant HTML and CSS here and do not use screenshots. Also, are you using Angular? That's significant and you need to tag that.

Comment: Any chance we could take a look at the code?

Comment: Did you visit the link before? The first more generic style is also applied to `:visited`

Comment: @Rob - Relevant CSS has been added. The project is using Angular, but I'm not a developer working on that portion of the project.

Comment: @Sidney - That's probably not possible at the moment.  I'd need to get approval to push a build to a public facing server... which is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Ihazkode - OMG, I'm a dummy. You are correct. Since it was grayed out, I didn't think that rule was being applied... I was wrong. (I wish Firefox highlighted the active pseudo-class being applied as well.)

Comment: By the way, if you are not sure if a page is rendered in quirks mode or standards mode, Firefox says which one in its View Page Info popup.

Comment: We still need the markup that shows the problem: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're looking for is called [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Briefly, every rule in your style sheet is given a weight based on the types of selectors used in the rule definition.

A common way of representing this is called base-10 specificity.

To calculate a base-10 specificity, you take:

```
  The number of elements and pseudo-elements * 1
+ The number of elements and pseudo-elements * 10
+                         The number of ID's * 100
+ For inline styles                            1000
+ For !important properties (not rules)        10000
```

So for this rule: `#mypage .rule1:hover p:before`

```
P & :before     = 2 * 1   =   1
.rule1 & :hover = 2 * 10  =  20
#mypage         = 1 * 100 = 100
For a total specificity of: 121
```

All matching rules are applied from least specific to most specific, with properties overriding the previous values.

Multiple rules of the same specificity are applied in the order they appear in your style sheet.

Properties with the `!important` flag also override based on specificity when more than one rule with the `!important` flag.

That should be enough to get you started. Note that the base-10 method is not actually used by the browser, but rather is just an easy way to do the math in your head. So 11 elements do not override a class, even though the math would suggest otherwise.